# Is there always a free $\mathbb{Q}$-module on a set $A$?

Tags: modules

As the title says;

> Is there always a free $\mathbb{Q}$-module on a set $A$?

I believe so, since you can always form the free $\mathbb{Z}$-module on a set $A$, $F(A)$ and then identify $\mathbb{Z}$ as a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: How does identifying $\mathbb{Z}$ as a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ do anything? In any case, yes, there is always such a free module, and $\mathbb{Q}$ can be replaced with any ring.

Comment: You're right that the free $\Bbb Q$-module will always have a submodule which is a free $\Bbb Z$-module on $A$. Technically you could go from the free $\Bbb Z$-module to the free $\Bbb Q$-module, but that's confusing and takes way more effort than you need! Since you're happy the free $\Bbb Z$-module exists, just look at the proof of that and replace "$\Bbb Z$" with "$\Bbb Q$". In general in algebra, "the free object on $A$" will [usually exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_object#Existence). This is not actually much harder to prove that existence of free $\Bbb Z$-modules.